# Keras real time training log Repeating - Progress-bar print Again and Again in each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In our task, the following are the output metrics; It's a multi-class classification problem.

```
- loss, gra_loss, vow_loss, cons_loss
- gra_acc, vow_acc, cons_acc
```

We use **Keras** and facing the following weird behaviour of it very often.

> Epoch 1/15 2043/5021 [===========>..................] - **ETA: 9:19** -
>   loss: 2.7695 - gra_loss: 1.9486 - vow_loss: 0.4557 - cons_loss: 0.3652
>   - gra_acc: 0.5240 - vow_acc: 0.8583 - cons_acc: 0.88628- **ETA: 15**: - **ETA: 14:02** - loss: 4.3086 - gra_los - **ETA: 12:20** - loss: 3.5839 -
>   gra_loss: 2.5652 - vow_loss: 0.5682 - cons_loss: 0.4505 - gra_acc:
>   0.4002 - vow_acc: 0.821 - **ETA: 12:15** - loss: 3.5549 - gra_loss: 2.5434 - vow_loss: 0.5640 - cons_loss: 0.4475 - gra_ - **ETA: 12:04** - loss: 3.4868 - gra_ - **ETA: 11:40** - loss: 3.3581 - gra_loss: 2.3925 - vow_loss: 0.5375 - cons_loss: 0.4281 - gra_acc: 0.4330 - vow_acc:
>   0.8317  - **ETA: 11:36** - loss - E - **ETA: 10:41** - loss: 3.0747 - gra_loss: 2.1817 - vow_loss: 0.4961 - cons_loss: - **ETA: 10:28** - loss:
>   3.0218 - gra_loss: 2.1407 - vow_loss: 0.4 - **ETA: 10:12** - loss: 2.9572 - gra_loss: 2.0909 - vow_loss: 0.4797 - cons_loss: - **ETA: 9:59** - loss: 2.9056 - gra_loss: 2.0 - **ETA: 9:49** - loss: 2.8 - ETA - **ETA: 9:24** - loss: 2.7843 - gra_loss: 1.9599 - vow_loss: 0.4575 - cons_loss: 0.3669
>   - gra

To provide more information here is the `callback` function that I've used.

```py
    # learning rate reduction
    def scheduler(epoch):
        if epoch < 10:
            return 0.001
        else:
            return 0.001 * (0.8 ** epoch)

    # -----------------------
    # ----------------- model compiling ---------
    model.compile(

        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001), 

        loss = {'gra' : 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                'vow' : 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                'cons': 'categorical_crossentropy'},

        loss_weights = {'gra' : 1.0,
                        'vow' : 1.0,
                        'cons': 1.0},

        metrics={'gra' : 'accuracy', 
                 'vow' : 'accuracy', 
                 'cons': 'accuracy'}
    )

    # -----------------------
    # -------------- define some function for callback --------
    def Call_Back():
        # model check point
        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('mod.h5', 
                                     monitor = 'val_loss', 
                                     verbose = 0, save_best_only=True, 
                                     mode = 'min',
                                     save_weights_only = True)

        lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
        csv_logger = CSVLogger('log.csv')
        early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                              mode='min', patience=30)

        # tensorboard --logdir ./Graph 
        # http://localhost:6006
        tfcallback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', histogram_freq=0,  
              write_graph=True, write_images=True)

        return [checkpoint, tfcallback, csv_logger, lr_scheduler]
```

Then, Simply as usual

```
# calling all callbacks 
callbacks = Call_Back()

train_history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=int(len(train_labels)/batch_size), 
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps = int(len(val_labels)/batch_size),
    verbose=1,
    epochs=epoch,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

Comment: How exactly are you viewing this output? In a terminal? Coming from a log file?

Comment: just normally, in jupter notebook. no terminal, no log file.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I update the info, please see at the bottom of the post.